# Loop through a set of words and then use regex to remove the words from text

Tags: python, regex, loops, for-loop

I have a set of words (this set of words is dynamic so I have to use `for` loop)

```
a = {'i', 'the', 'at', 'it'}
```

And I have a text

```
text = 'i want to jump the rope. i will do it tomorrow at 5pm. i love to jump the rope.'
```

Now I am trying to remove the word from the text but somehow it's not working. Here is what I am using:

```
for word in a:
    text = re.sub(r'\bword\b', '', text).strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is looking for the literal string `"word"`. You should use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to use the value stored in the variable named `word`:

```
text = re.sub(rf'\b{word}\b', '', text).strip()
```

Comment: Ah neat. For some reason I didn't think you could combine `f''` and `r''` strings!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is that you are looking for the literal string "word". You're after:

```py
text=re.sub(rf'\b{word}\b', '', text).strip()
```

This adds the actual value of `word` into the string.

When working debugging regex, it helps to log the match so you can check it is doing what you expect.

```py
import re;

a={'i', 'the', 'at', 'it'}
text='i want to jump the rope. i will do it tomorrow at 5pm. i love to jump the rope.'

for word in a:
    print(f'Updating text, removing "{word}" from: "{text}"')
    # text=re.sub(r'\bword\b', '', text).strip()
    print(re.search(r'\bword\b', text))
```

> Updating text, removing "at" from: "i want to jump the rope. i will do it tomorrow at 5pm. i love to jump the rope."
>
> None

You can see that this is not finding a match, but if we simplify your expression:

```py
print(re.search(word, text))
```

> Updating text, removing "it" from: "i want to jump the rope. i will do it tomorrow at 5pm. i love to jump the rope."
>
> <re.Match object; span=(35, 37), match='it'>

This does find a match, this suggests something is going wrong in your conversion to regex.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) is really useful for diagnosing such things. Simply print the actual regex out, and test it against the input:

```py
print(r'\bword\b')
print(rf'\b{word}\b')
```

> \bword\b
>
> \bthe\b

---

You probably also want to tidy up the white-space, you can do like this:

```py
text=re.sub(rf'\b{word}\s?\b', '', text).strip()
```

> want to jump rope. will do tomorrow 5pm. love to jump rope.

Answer (score -1):

Why import a library and not just use `replace()` instead?

```
list_words = {'i', 'the', 'at', 'it'}
text = 'i want to jump the rope. i will do it tomorrow at 5pm. i love to jump the rope.'

for word in list_words:
    text = text.replace(word, "")
```

**EDIT**

**This has a flaw, as pointed out by Seluck in the comment below.**

Comment: Because it doesn't work. `\b` means word boundary, which your solution doesn't take into account. Have you tested this?

Comment: It removes all instances of the strings in `list_words` that occur in `text`, even in cases when it is not a word such as 'i' in will. I missed that, my bad. 
By the way, it was an honest question. I didn't think it would make sense to create a new question, but I am not yet allowed to publish comments either on other people's answers or on the original question. So I posted the question as an answer, also because it is a question other people may think of. What is the harm?

Comment: Also, there is still another potential solution that uses only built-in functions:

`text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in list_words])`

Tho it might be too inefficient. What do you think?

Comment: Note that word boundaries doesn't have to be whitespace only; they can also be punctuations. Your second attempt still doesn't work for cases like `"hello,world"`. Regex is the right tool here.

Comment: It works if the same separator is used between all words, which is the case for this question.

Comment: Not really. It won't work if `rope` is in the stop word list.